# Strapi Body-Parser File Size Settings

Tags: body-parser, strapi

I am trying to upload a file to the Strapi API, but I keep getting an error that my file is too large.  I want to send a 1mb file.  Usually in Express/Koa I could change the body-parser settings like this:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));
```

But since Strapi is such a closed off system, I am not sure where to set or edit this.

All help and pointers are greatly appreciated!  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In v3.x.x the settings are apparently now located in `./config/middleware.js`

And it turns out that increasing the file size was not enough, you also have to make sure the `formLimit` and `jsonLimit` are also increased.

```
    parser: {
        //..
        formLimit: '50mb', <--
        jsonLimit: '50mb', <--
        formidable: {
            maxFileSize: 50 * 1024 * 1024, // 50MB
        },
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the setting in the parser middleware.
From the [docs](https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/plugins/upload.html#upload):

> The library we use is koa-body, and itself uses the node-formidable library to process files.
> You can pass configuration to the middleware directly by setting it in the parser middleware configuration

Locations:
`./config/request.json` (stable)
`./config/environments/development/request.json` (pre stable)

```
{
  "parser": {
    //Other settings
    //...
    //This is what you're looking for
    "formidable": {
      "maxFileSize": 20000000 // defaults to 200mb
    }
  }
}
```