# Big files upload on Strapi

Tags: javascript, upload, strapi

I'm new to Strapi and im doing a video upload site (front on React). The problem is that i need to upload big video files. I'm on strapi v3.1.1, the first problem was the limitation on the file upload(was 200MB), but i changed the maxFileSize on the `node_modules/formidable/lib/incoming_form.js`. Now the file seems to upload until the end, but after that the strapi is returning an error:

```
error RangeError [ERR_FS_FILE_TOO_LARGE]: File size (3371964008) is greater than possible Buffer: 2147483647 bytes
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterStat [as oncomplete] (fs.js:277:11)
```

*I found on internet that i should change the maxFileLimit in config/environments/development/request.json, but my config folder does not has such folders/files..

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are right, it's possible and you need to change exactly that file.
You are probably just looking at docs that are not for your version. The location of the config files has changed over one of the recent updates.

For Strapi 3.0.0 Stable you need to put these settings in `./config/middleware.js`

From the [docs](https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/migration-guide/migration-guide-beta.20-to-3.0.0.html#middlewares):

> Middlewares We have moved all the middleware related configurations
> into one place: `./config/middleware.js`
>
> The middlewares were previously configured in mutliple files:
>
> ```
> ./config/middleware.json
> ./config/application.json
> ./config/language.json
> ./config/environments/{env}/request.json
> ./config/environments/{env}/response.json
> ./config/environments/{env}/security.json
> ```

The actual change is not complex, just a value in a json file. Check [this answer out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62812600/strapi-body-parser-file-size-settings/62813080#62813080) for an example.

Comment: Can't find the request.json on the path you said. I've just post an image of my strapi folder as you can see...

Comment: @GBenitez Can you post full list of files in ./config? 
Also - what version of Strapi are you using?